# Ansible List Default

Tags: ansible

In ansible is it possible to have a list in the `defaults/main.yml` file, I want to set permissions on group of files but I want to use a default list in my role that can be overridden.

`defaults/main.yml`

```
libexec_path: /opt/nagios/libexec
libexec_owner: nagios
libexec_group: www-data
run_as_root:
  - check_dhcp
  - check_icmp
```

`tasks/main.yml`

```
# Files needing to run as root u+s
- file:
    path: "{{ libexec_path }}/{{ item }}"
    owner: root
    group: "{{ libexec_group }}"
    mode: 4775
    with_items: "{{ run_as_root }}"
```

However I keep getting the error:

> FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "The task includes an option with
>   an undefined variable. The error was: 'item' is undefined...

I've tried setting

```
strategy: debug
```

in the main yml file and the debugger reports:

> u'run_as_root': [u'check_dhcp', u'check_icmp'],

so it is being set, so why won't it iterate over it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix the indentation!

```
- file:
    path: "{{ libexec_path }}/{{ item }}"
    owner: root
    group: "{{ libexec_group }}"
    mode: 4775
  with_items: "{{ run_as_root }}"
```

You have an error message clearly saying `item` is not defined; **not** `run_as_root`. And you would have the same error if you specified the list directly under `with_items`.